# CMD + N to navigate windows in Ventura

Tags: terminal, keyboard, iterm, ventura

I use `Cmd + Number` to navigate to different windows as is the case in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59302975/iterm2-keyboard-shortcut-for-navigating-between-windows#). However, in Ventura I can't find how to make the change from `Opt + Cmd + Number` to `Cmd + Number` as the preferences menu has changed pretty drastically.

How do I change this in Ventura?

FWIW - Apple M1 Max, Ventura 13.0

Comment: Question referred is about iTerm2 and moving between it's windows. Accepted answer provides correct location of appropriate  iTerm2 preference.

Comment: Thank you. I thought these were global preference. Will mark as duplicate since I am working with iTerm2

Comment: Actually can't mark as dup since the other answer is on SO.